# show extra column items grid order

Tags: magento-1.8, adminhtml, sales, order-grid

I have added a extra column in sales_flat_quote_item table. Populating the column during checkout works fine. But showing the values of the extra column on the order details page in admin does not work. I also would like to show the extra column in the order confirmation email.

can you please tell me how to get the data from the column in these places?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that the quote and the order are two different things.

To get the value, when the order is created, you have to transfer the value from the quote to the order.

1. add the same "attribute" to the order as well (I recommend to use `Mage_Sales_Model_Entity_Setup` for creating the new columns)
2. add the conversion to the config.xml

   ```
   <fieldsets>
       <sales_convert_quote>
           <custom_attribute>
               <to_order>*</to_order>
           </custom_attribute>
       </sales_convert_quote>
       <sales_convert_order>
           <custom_attribute>
               <to_quote>*</to_quote>
           </custom_attribute>
       </sales_convert_order>
   </fieldsets>
   ```

[More on this at atwix.](http://www.atwix.com/magento/custom-product-attribute-quote-order-item/)